# How do I send Call Log history via sms in Android?

Tags: android, sms, calllog

I'm trying to send `CallLog` history via sms. Well the `CallLog` history is displaying in `TextView` but SMS is not working.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_log);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call);

    getCallDetails();
}


private void getCallDetails() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append( "Call Details :");
    while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
    String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
    switch( dircode ) {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
    dir = "OUTGOING";
    break;

    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
    dir = "INCOMING";
    break;

    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
    dir = "MISSED";
    break;
    }
    sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();


    String str = sb.toString();
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage("5554", null, str, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to send sms in background only or is it okay if sms compose screen will come into picture?

Comment: @PratikSharma in Background

Comment: Okay. See the solution I have posted below. I have verify that solution and it is working well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it possible your message string length is more then one message length so use [smsManager. divideMessage (String text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#divideMessage%28java.lang.String%29) for sending message if string exceed SMS size limit  as:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 

if(str.length()>160){
    ArrayList<String> smses = smsManager.divideMessage(str);  

        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("5554", null,
                    smses, null, null);
 }
else{
      sms.sendTextMessage("5554", null, smses, null, null);
 }
```

and make sure you have added following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thanks! but Can't we able to send in a Single message?

Comment: @Learner678 : just check if condition because i'm not confirm about message length that's why i have used 160 you can search for default message length and check if then it will work in both cases. try after changing `if(str.length()>130)` instead of `if(str.length()>160)`

Comment: Alright! I have changed to some other digits, but still the message is breaking into more than one.

Comment: @Learner678 : this is another issue dear just check it on real device or make an new question about this issue thanks do much

Comment: I removed sms coding and displayed in `TextView`. Its working on Emulator. I tried running on real device, its showing error **12-15 16:54:36.660: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider uri content://call_log/calls from pid=4278, uid=10094 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS**  Already I included permission in Manifest.

Comment: @Learner678 : ok post your Manifest

Comment: Now I Included `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` in Manifest and its working on real device. In emulator its working without adding `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is working well.

```
SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault();

String phoneNumber="xxxxxxxxxx";
String message="test text message";

sm.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

I think you need to add this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

I tried it and it charged me too for 1 sent sms. :)

Hope it helps you.

THanks.

Comment: I want to send Call Log History as sms:)) And ρяσѕρєя K's code working!

Comment: what is the total length of your Call Log History string?

Comment: Sorry!!  Don't know. How to fetch that?

Comment: `str.length();` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

to send call log in message

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> part = sms.divideMessage(sb.toString());
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage("number to whom u wanna send", null, part, null, null);
```

now the receiver side will deal it as one message i try this block of its send in multi part but receive in one block of message

**sender side**

[image: sender side]

**receiver side**

[image: receiver side]